# BigQuery in Perl: append query data to table

Tags: perl, google-bigquery

I am using Perl to drive BigQuery and I am trying to insert a job that will populate a table from the results of a query. The error I am getting is "Required parameter is missing". Which parameter is that? (it would be nice if the error message was more specific)

Here is the code:

```
$response = $bq->request(
resource => 'jobs',
method => 'insert',
content => {
    configuration => { 
        query => {
        query => $query,
        destinationTable => {
            project_id => $project_id,
            dataset_id => $dataset_id,
            tableId => $table_id,
        },
        createDisposition => "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        writeDisposition => "WRITE_APPEND",
        allowLargeResults =>"TRUE",
        },
    },
},
async => $async,
);
```

Note that if I skip the destinationTable part, the code works fine, but it puts the results in a temporary table. So this works:

```
$response = $bq->request(
resource => 'jobs',
method => 'insert',
content => {
    configuration => { 
        query => {
        query => $query,
        createDisposition => "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        writeDisposition => "WRITE_APPEND",
        },
    },
},
async => $async,
);
```

Any ideas? Don't be put off by the fact this is Perl, it behaves the same way as Python, only the format is different.

Comment: have you tried adding flattenResults? another option  - check naming - projectId, datasetId; flattenResults is optional, so most likely latter

Comment: My guess is that you either want to consistently camel-case the fields within `destinationTable` as `projectId`, `datasetId`, and `tableId`, or consistently underscore them as `project_id`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
    destinationTable => {
        projectId => $project_id,
        datasetId => $dataset_id,
        tableId => $table_id,
    },
```

Comment: Thanks; that was it. I found it accidentally right after I posted it. It only took me 3 hours of frustration &@#$&!$%. I am royally annoyed at google for not even providing decent error messages. Forget about coding examples.

Comment: understood :o) you still can vote or accept the answer if you think it answers your question (which i think it is) - so later users can see the right answer. totally up to you though! thanks for update

Comment: I wonder if I can do the same, i.e., point the output to a destination table, if instead of a query I just list the table. The difference is, the list command is free...